# How to hide/remove GhostKit component panel in gutenberg block inspector

Tags: filters, block-editor

is there a way how can I hide/remove components panel?

There is one panel created by plugin GhostKit and I need to remove it, because it's not working properly and our users try to use it and it cause a lot of problems... it's Animate On Scroll panel

Answer (score 1):

Ok, nevermind, I found solution
I've tried `removeFilter( 'editor.BlockEdit', 'ghostkit/sr/additional-attributes' );` but it was not working inside my plugin, but it worked in console, so then I found out, that I need to hook this to something, so this is working solution

```
addAction( 'plugins.pluginRegistered', 'kubiq/remove-ghostkit-animations', function( settings, name ){
    if( name == 'ghostkit' ){
        removeFilter( 'editor.BlockEdit', 'ghostkit/sr/additional-attributes' );
    }
});
```